# onclick event on img tag or anchor tag?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Two ways to make a clickable button:

Method 1:

```
<img src="image.png" alt="" id="btn_img" />
```

Method 2:

```
<a id="btn_img"><img src="image.png" alt="" /></a>
```

Apart from CSS rendering difference (e.g. the cursor, the blue image border produced by IE), if I assign a `click` event to the id `btn_img`, is there any behavioral difference, e.g. cross-browser compatibility? and the most important question, which method is preferred?

The code to add event:

```
$('#btn_img').click(function() {
  alert('do something');
});
```

*hope this question won't fall into "opinion-based" category.*

Comment: If someone has JavaScript disabled, then the first method will fail.

Comment: both will fail, as both are triggered by jQuery.

Comment: Well my point was really that an anchor tag will work (with a valid href) while the JS only solution can fail.

Comment: agreed with that. though it's getting more lightbox-like effects in website than pure hyperlinks to other pages.

Comment: `return false;` after the "do something" in your function if you go the anchor route though. Otherwise your page will refresh. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both results are the same. The only difference is that the click event is triggered in the image in the first method and in the link tag in second method. So we need to prevent the default behavior of the `a tag` but not the `img tag`. Anyway, in regards to styling purposes, wrapping the `img tag` with any element would be better than that not wrapping it, so it's better practice to use the second method.